# mod_userdir permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris

I installed apache2 on my opensolaris server and enabled mod_userdir, but when I browse to ~userdir I get 403 error even though public_html is set to world-readable, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set directory permission in the httpd.conf
So I put

```
<Directory "/home">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to my httpd.conf file and it worked

Comment: This is not a forum, and this post is not an Answer. Please edit this information into the Question. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not only does public_html need to be world readable, but apache has to have permission to decend into /home/*username* (the parent directory) as well. I would put money on the fact that the user's home directory is owned to them alone, with permissions 700. This would need to be 701 at a minimum.

A tip someone taught me if the logs don't turn anything up:

Temporarily set the user running Apache with an actual login shell of your choice. Browse to the public_html directory one step at a time.

`cd /

cd home

cd username

cd public_html`

Wherever it errors is the source of your 403.

Whenever you're done **MAKE SURE TO REMOVE THE LOGIN SHELL FROM APACHE**.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error_log file for the exact error, it should tell you precisely where Apache attempted to access to serve data. If that isn't where you expect it, check your mod_userdir config.